# Toggleclass stops working on page reload, how to keep it active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a toggleClass on click with prevent default that works on click but when i reload the page, the menu won't toggle on click, although, it will continue to check the width for toggle.

The Javascript checks width on load and remove or adds class based on width as well as on window size change.  It also allows for a click toggle.

**Here's the code for it:**

```
$(function(){
    function checkWidthAndToggle() {
        if($(window).width()<=992){
            $("#wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
        }else{
            $("#wrapper").addClass("toggled");
        }
    }

    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });

    $(window).resize(checkWidthAndToggle);
    checkWidthAndToggle();
});
```

How can I continue to allow the `toggleClass` after a page reload?

I also use turbolinks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use turbolinks 5 (turbolinks in ruby on rails 5), you should add event listener for `turbolinks:load` event.

More: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#observing-navigation-events

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what EXACTLY the problem was but what I did was added a

//= require file_name.js

within my application.js file near the top and solved the issue.

I noticed when I moved the //= require tree . to the top, this issue would go away. So I just instead required the file itself so it loads ahead of most other files. I use Bootstrap, jQuery and turbolinks so I assume one of those was interfering on the load.

Comment: This will not be an accepted answer as i do notice requiring the file interferes with other javascript.  I have been able to solve some interfering JS with adding the `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"...` on some pages but not working for all JS interference